# Word for a person or code which puts emphasis on self-improvement

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word which describes a person or ethical/religious code or whatever which emphasises self-improvement. That is, that the point of it is to fix one's flaws and vices and whatnot.

I've found two words which are close but not exactly what I mean - *ascetic* might work except that suggests a real strictness about it, whilst *virtuous* might be something to strive towards, and not the actual belief in wanting to become one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is ***[self religion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_religion)***:

> A self religion (or self-religion) is a religious or self-improvement group which has as one of its primary aims the improvement of the self

---

Also ***stoicism*** has [self-help](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-help) (self-improvement) ideology in it.

> The [Stoics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoicism) taught that destructive emotions resulted from errors in judgment, and that a sage, or person of "moral and intellectual perfection," would not suffer such emotions.
>
> Philosophy for a Stoic is not just a set of beliefs or ethical claims, it is a way of life involving constant practice and training (or askesis, see asceticism)

---

A word for a person or concept that puts emphasis on self-improvement would be ***["flourishing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flourishing)***.

> In positive psychology, flourishing is “to live within an optimal range of human functioning, one that connotes goodness, generativity, growth, and resilience.”

Thus, ***[eudaimonia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eudaimonia)*** or eudaimonism is a related concept. It is a Greek word but it is also a loan word in English. In modern psychology, it is conceptualized in six factors, one of which is **personal growth**.

> Eudaimonia, sometimes anglicized as eudaemonia or eudemonia , is a Greek word commonly translated as happiness or welfare; however, "**human flourishing**" has been proposed as a more accurate translation.
>
> Etymologically, it consists of the words "eu" ("good") and "daimōn" ("spirit"). It is a central concept in Aristotelian ethics and political philosophy, along with the terms "**aretē**", most often translated as "**virtue**" or "**excellence**", and "**phronesis**", often translated as "practical or ethical wisdom".

Comment: Check [Self-evaluation motives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-evaluation_motives) also

Answer (score 0):

[Self-improver](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/self+improver):

> One that improves  one's mind, character, etc., through one's own efforts.

Answer (score 0):

You might describe such a person, code, or whatever as being morally or ethically [aspirational](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/aspirational).

Answer (score 0):

**Reformation** would be the process of reforming.

> the action or process of reforming an institution or practice.

[reform](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reform)

> make changes in (something, typically a social, political, or economic
>   institution or practice) in order to improve it.

It is a word that is used in a lot of religious contexts but also works for everyman context.

In a much simpler context you could say that you are trying to *better yourself*.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider *self-actualization* or *self-actualizer.*

Definition of SELF-ACTUALIZE

:  to realize fully one's potential

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/selfactualization?show=0&t=1402005353

Answer (score 0):

**Self-communion**  n. Communion with one's self; thoughts about one's self. [1913 Webster]

Even ecclesiastically, 'self-communion' is to acknowledge and mend

Answer (score -1):

How about [**perfectionism**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/perfectionist)?

> [**perfectionism**](http://www.religioustolerance.org/gl_p.htm): a doctrine in certain religions that moral or spiritual perfection can be achieved before the soul has passed into the afterlife

Comment: Perfectionism usually isn't referred to in that sense, though. A perfectionist is someone who has to get a perfect score on a test or make sure their code project builds with no errors or warnings. It does not carry religious connotations to most people.

Comment: @Dispensador I quite agree with you on that. But it doesn't necessarily mean that "perfectionism"  does not also carry a theological/religious sense to it. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perfectionism